# C# Windows Universal App ListView Selected Item Content

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm building a Universal Windows App and using the ListView, upon click I can't seem to get the selected item text/item details in general..

My XAML Code:

```
            <ListView Name="listviews" Margin="10,172,10,0" Tapped="listviews_Tapped" SelectionChanged="listviews_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bookings.ID}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Bookings.first}" FontSize="24"></Run>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Bookings.last}" FontSize="32"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Tag="{Binding Bookings.ID}">
                        <Run Text="Total: "/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Bookings.pax}" />
                        <Run Text=" - M: "/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Bookings.total_male}"></Run>
                        <Run Text=" / F: "/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Bookings.total_female}"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitch1" OnContent="Checked-in" OffContent="Waiting" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I tried using Tapped & SelectionChanged but can't seem to grab the data... Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what the problem is. I do not see any issues with the XAML you provided

Comment: When I permit the tapping on an item, I can't grab the selected item name/info.

Comment: again. please provide more information. Can you show the code behind you are using

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch it on ItemClick event , you must set ListView's ItemClickEnabled property to True and SelectionMode to none.

After that , in the second parameter of ItemCLick event handler (e parameter usually) you can catch your model with e.ClickedItem property.

Don't forget to cast it to your Model like :

```
var myClickedItem = e.ClickedItem as Bookings
```

Comment: Sadly e.ClickedItem doesn't seem to exist in Visual Studio 2015 C# Universal Apps...

Comment: It is , I am sure :) It's nothing to do with your Visual Studio version.ListView and GridView have ItemClickEventArgs described here. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemclickeventargs

Comment: Unfortunately it seems not to work for Windows 10/Phone 10-Universal.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add this to your Page.cs file:

```
void listviews_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Bookings SelectedBook = (Bookings)listviews.SelectedItem;
    var abc = SelectedBook.ID;
}
```

Now you can access all properties of Bookings-typed object using SelectedBook.xyz